# Unable to start the name node in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I am installing hadoop on my ubuntu machine where i am unable to start my name node it is shutting down giving this error.

```
15/08/18 16:30:43 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

My bash variable configuration is this

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
```

How do i get rid of it?

Update
The log continues from the above warning
see this

```
Formatting using clusterid: CID-b70f07df-f1dc-486d-9077-d19f9e5ae5be
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: No KeyProvider found.
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsLock is fair:true
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager:     dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager:  dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check=true
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.namenode.startup.delay.block.deletion.sec is set to 000:00:00:00.000
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: The block deletion will start around 2015 Aug 18 17:16:19
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO util.GSet: 2.0% max memory 889 MB = 17.8 MB
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication         = 1
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication             = 1
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: shouldCheckForEnoughRacks  = false
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: encryptDataTransfer        = false
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxNumBlocksToLog          = 1000
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             = root (auth:SIMPLE)
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = true
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map INodeMap
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO util.GSet: 1.0% max memory 889 MB = 8.9 MB
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^20 = 1048576 entries
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: ACLs enabled? false
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: XAttrs enabled? true
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: Maximum size of an xattr: 16384
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map cachedBlocks
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO util.GSet: 0.25% max memory 889 MB = 2.2 MB
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^18 = 262144 entries
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 30000
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.window.num.buckets = 10
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf:  dfs.namenode.top.num.users = 10
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.windows.minutes = 1,5,25
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache on namenode is  enabled
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache will use 0.03 of total heap and retry cache entry expiry time is 600000 millis
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map NameNodeRetryCache
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory 889 MB = 273.1 KB
15/08/18 17:16:19 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory /home/hadoopspace/hdfs/namenode ? (Y or N) n
Format aborted in Storage Directory /home/hadoopspace/hdfs/namenode
15/08/18 17:16:23 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
15/08/18 17:16:23 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at shaggie-Inspiron-5558/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Comment: It is just a warning. show the output of this command hadoop dfs -ls /

Answer (score 0):

You can try exporting "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${HADOOP_PREFIX/HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native" variable in your profile or bashrc.